# Does spark sql have non-clustered index functionality?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to ask if spark sql support non-clustered index like sql server does? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It relies on partitioning and grouping of data in dataframes with join technologies and is a processing engine, not a database.

Predicate push down on some sources is of course supported with partition pruning when reading from them.

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to maintain the non-clustered index ability, and frequent insertion ability of database  and also the fast loading of parquet files. What are my options? I am currently experimenting with SQL server and the loading and writing speed of a large dataframe is not very optimal compared to dask with parquet...

Comment: Parquet is verg fast as it maintains all types of stats to avoid reading blocks of data if no records meeg uour search criteria.